# How to detect a attached/detached peripheral in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, hardware, microphone

How can i detect the connection or disconnection of a external peripheral (like a microphone) in React Native at runtime?

I need to it for both iOS and Android devices.

Comment: any solution? thanks advance